# Push() location, change URL in address bar but it doesn't render component

Tags: node.js, reactjs, express, react-router, react-router-redux

I use `express` as a nodeJs web application server and `react-redux-router` to `push` new location to the browser. After pushing the address in the address bar from `localhost:3000/admin` change to `localhost:3000` but it keeps on the same page.

I use `dispatch(push('/'))` to execute the job.

> redux-logger :
>   [image]

[Update]

I used [this solution](https://github.com/ReactTraining/react-router/blob/master/packages/react-router/docs/guides/redux.md) but it didn't work for me

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Wrapping components with [withRouter](https://github.com/ReactTraining/react-router/blob/master/packages/react-router/docs/api/withRouter.md) solved my problem.